# Time traveller destroys the universe by going fifteen minutes back

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I am looking for a veryshort story from the 1960s about a time traveller who travels back in time fifteen minutes only to tell the person he meets that the amount of energy it took to propel him back in time destroys the universe.

Answer (score 14):

This is **["The Man from When"](https://bestshortstories.org/man-from-when/)** by Dannie Plachta.

It first appeared in *Worlds of If Science Fiction*, July 1966.

[image]

You correctly recall that the story was very short (only 2 pages, pp. 77-78).  However, you incorrectly recall how far back he travelled.  **It was 18 minutes.**

Comment: Was it worth it?

Comment: "You see, there was such an expenditure of energy that it completely wiped out the Earth of my time." The Earth, not the universe. By the way, for us wretched souls who don't have a copy of the July 1966 *If*, the [ISFDB](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?70682) mentions a couple of anthologies containing that story.